# PHP and HTML Radio error

Tags: php, html, input, radio-button

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$firstQuestion == true;
if($firstQuestion == true) {
 ?>
 <script>alert('firstQuestion is true');</script>
 <h1>1. YES OR NO?</h1>
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
 <input type="radio" name="1" id="yes" class="yes" value="yes" checked="checked"><label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="no" class="no" value="no"><label for="no">No</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form> <?php
}
if(isset($_POST ['submit'])) {
$firstQuestion == false;
if($_POST ['1'] === 'yes') {
    echo 'Input was recieved as yes';
} else {
    echo 'Input was recieved as no';
}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, the first form does not appear.
I could place the form in the body then make it disappear using javascript, but this is the beginning of a bigger project which will echo out many more questions depending on the answers, so the javascript method is much more inefficient.

Comment: It should be inside body tag

Comment: Well yeah, it's entirely outside the DOM so it shouldn't render. I suggest you read up a bit on HTML, DOM, Javascript, AJAX, and PHP. At least the basics, so you understand what each part does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the whole stuff in the php tags into the body tag (`<body> <?php $firstQuestion = true; //and so on... ?> </body>`). So the browser can render this DOM structure. This is the most important thing when you code HTML.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work... [Here's](http://bambakids.com/libat) what I have right now. Nothing shows up even if you put it in the body.

Comment: Somehow you don't output something. My web browser returns the following: 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>`

Can you post your code here?

Comment: Well, mine just doesn't output the form. it **does** output `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> </body> </html>`. Also, [here's](http://bambakids.com/libat) a link to where I'm trying this.

Comment: The php code that is in the question is the php code. I just moved it into the body.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/910pVaJv You cannot assign a value to a variable with the '==' operator, you have to use the '=' operator.